# Is it possible for an activity's onDestroy to be called without onCreate being called?

Tags: android, android-activity, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Activity that assigns an object to a field in an Activity's onCreate() and access that object in onDestroy(). The field isn't assigned anywhere else.

My problem is that I have 2 crash reports indicating that the field is null in onDestroy. The only options I can think of are:

- A) onDestroy() is being called before onCreate() or
- B) This is some sort of Mono bug and onDestroy() is actually running in
  a different instance of the .NET activity.

Here is a cut down example.

```
public sealed class MainActivity : Activity{
    private _disposable;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _disposable = new Disposable();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        // NRE exception here ( _disposable is null )
        if(_disposable.Guard())
        {
            ...
        }
        base.OnDestroy();    
    }
}
```

Ignoring the fact that this is a Xamarin Android app, I really want to know if the A) case possible? Should I rule it out completely and assume the bug is somewhere else OR is it possible for onDestroy() to be called before onCreate() and I should guard against it.

Comment: I'm not a .NET guy but it seems that `OnDestroy` is declared outside of the class.

Comment: Try adding prints to the log after `_disposable = new Disposable();` and before the NPE. (Or, run with debugger and use breakpoints).

Comment: I can't reproduce the crash, so can't use logging unfortunately. The crash and stack trace are coming back from a crash reporting service. The app has been out for 24 months and had a few hundred thousand sessions. This crash has only happened twice but I still want to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: A bug that you can't reproduce you probably can't solve. That said, what you *can* do is work around it by setting a null check in your destroy method.

Comment: The variable is probably being released after onStop() is called.

Comment: Late to an old party but I think Disposable should implement the Dispose interface. Then with modern C# you could do a:

Disposable?.Dispose(); call and whatever lives in Guard could either be moved to the dispose methods logic or calld from there. The ?. will do the null check for you before calling the method.